# Installing Coffeescript redux

Tags: coffeescript

I found this [link](http://ryanflorence.com/2012/coffeescript-source-maps/) to enable debugging in coffeescript.

But My problem is I am on windows 7 and I am not sure if there is way to run the make deps /call the make file, since the coffee file in the bin directory is not .exe file...what is the alternative/ How to install coffeescriptredux in windows.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a native executable, it's just javascript so you can install [node.js](http://nodejs.org/), install it with npm, and run it with node.js.

A bash console is nice when working with nodejs scripts (also with python/ruby/... scripts), you can install one on windows by installing http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/ for exemple.
Using it you can easily execute scripts that uses a hashbang (`#!/usr/bin/env node`) like the coffeescript compiler.